# Inverse of identity minus exponential matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am trying to analytically find the inverse of a matrix given by:
\begin{align}
   W = \left( I - \alpha e^A \right)^{-1}, 
\end{align}
where $I$ is the identity matrix of appropriate size, $e^A$ denotes **elementwise** exponential of $A$ and
\begin{align}
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{ (1-1)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \frac{ (2-1)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & 
           \frac{ (3-1)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \dots  & \frac{ (n-1)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \\
           \frac{ (1-2)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \frac{ (2-2)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & 
           \frac{ (3-2)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \dots  & \frac{ (n-2)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
           \frac{ (1-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \frac{ (2-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & 
           \frac{ (3-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } & \dots  & \frac{ (N-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \\
        \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
so that I'm trying to find
\begin{align}
    W = \begin{bmatrix}
           1 - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 0^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 1^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 2^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } &
               \dots  & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (n-1)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } \\
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 1^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
           1 - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 0^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ 1^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } &
               \dots  & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (n-2)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (1-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (2-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } & 
             - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (3-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } &
               \dots  & 
           1 - \alpha \exp{ \left( \frac{ (N-N)^2 }{ \sigma^2 } \right) } \\
        \end{bmatrix}^{-1}.
\end{align}

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much,

Katie

Comment: Are you trying to find $W^{-1}$? That would be the last matrix because $(A^{-1})^{-1}$...

Comment: Your matrix $W$ has only zeros on the diagonal and is symmetric, have you tried diagonalisation?

Comment: How do you define $e^A$ ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your interest in my question. I'm trying to find W, as opposed to $W^{-1}$, as that would simply be $I - \alpha e^A$, which would be wonderfully easy! W unfortunately does not have 0's on the diagonal, but rather $1-\alpha$. I have looked at diagonalisation but haven't made much progress. Regarding the definition of $e^A$, I wondered if there were multiple definitions of a matrix exponential, which is why I included the expanded matrix at the end. I've simply taken the exponential of each matrix element. This may be wrong? Thanks again, Katie.

Comment: The classical  definition of $e^A$ corresponds to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Your question is confusing. As Damien has pointed out, $e^A$ usually means the **matrix** exponential $I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\frac{A^3}{3!}+\ldots$, but in the last part of your questions, you seem to have taken $e^A$ as the **entrywise** exponential of $A$. Please clarify the meaning of $e^A$ in your question.

Comment: Oh dear, in that case I have misunderstood the definition of a matrix exponential. How do you write the element-wise exponential of a matrix? Apologies for the confusion. Cheers, Katie.

Comment: Would the person who kindly added a solution for my question in the context of a matrix exponential possibly re-post it, or message it to me? It was still very useful in giving me ideas on how to approach my problem, and if I make certain assumptions I can re-pose my problem to conform to matrix exponential assumptions. It would be very much appreciated. Cheers, Katie (and happy new year!).